# Can I uninstall an application without a dialog?

Tags: java, android, android-package-managers

I'm writing launcher where I want to delete specific application on user click without calling remove intent. Can I do this?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I'd fear for my security if you could.

Comment: Yeah, but there is security tips on application installation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with **superuser** (root) **privileges**.

Just delete the corresponding apk in `/data/app/com.example.app-X.apk` and the folder `/data/data/com.example.app`

Apart from that, there is no other way.